# Enumerator changing to different class

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I have a string:

```
bottom_line = "some text"
```

When I create an enumerator from it with `enum_for`, and try to call `each` on it, I get an error:

```
z = bottom_line.enum_for
z.each {|item| item.scan(/some_regex/)}
# => undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000001f65350>
```

What is going on here?

When I chain `enum_for` with the method all in one line, it works:

```
z = bottom_line.enum_for(:scan, /some_regex/)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Cary - I had tried looking at the documentation prior but was look at the Enumerator documentation, and I didn't realize it passed the #each method through to the class of the underlying object, String in this case

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the documentation on [`Object#enum_for`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-enum_for) before asking.

`Object#enum_for` accepts 1+ parameters: the method to be called when enumeration is actually invoked (defaults to `:each`) and the splatted arguments to be passed to that method.

That said,

```
z = bottom_line.enum_for
```

is an absolute equivalent to:

```
z = bottom_line.enum_for(:each)
```

while the inlined version is

```
z = bottom_line.enum_for(:scan)
```

why would you expect them to behave the same way? To achieve the same functionality one might explicitly specify the method in the call to `enum_for`:

```
z = bottom_line.enum_for :scan
z.each(/some_regexp/) { |item| puts item }
```

Comment: upvoted for *looking at the documentation before asking* note

Answer (score 0):

`z.each` causes the method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) to be sent to `z`. `Enumerator#each` obtains the class of `enum_for`'s receiver (`bottom_line`), which is `String`. It then looks to invoke the method `String#each`. It doesn't find such an instance method in the `String` class, so it raises the exception you obtained.